# Testing whether string is a valid word

Tags: ispell

I want to test whether a string constitutes a valid word using `ispell`.

Here is my function

```
(defun is-valid-word (word)
  "Check if the WORD is valid using `ispell`."
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert word)
      (ispell-word)))

(let ((word "introspect"))
  (if (is-valid-word word)
      (message "'%s' is a valid word." word)
    (message "'%s' is NOT a valid word." word)))
```

upon which I am getting the error

```
(error "Marker points into wrong buffer"
```

Comment: I recommend you use \_\`\_ispell\_'\_ instead of \_\`\_ispell\_\`\_ in docstring.

Comment: @shynur: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the ispell source code to see if I could find something helpful.

I did it like this:

- `C-h f ispell`
- click on the name of the elisp file where the function is
- `M-x occur defun RET`

The function `occur` does a quick search through the buffer for a pattern and shows the results in a secondary buffer. You can navigate that buffer without leaving the primary buffer with `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` (or navigate it however you want).

Anyway, this way, I found a function that searched a lookup dictionary with a regular expression.

This means that `ispell-lookup-word` returns a list of all the words that match the expression.

`(member "introspect" (ispell-lookup-word "introspect"))`

This returns `nil` for me, because that word isn't in the dictionary in my system.

`(member "public" (ispell-lookup-word "public"))`, however, does return `("public")`.

See the documentation for `ispell-lookup-words` for how to customize or modify the behavior.

Do note that, like for everything else in emacs, the functions are only available if the library is loaded, so you will need to call `(require 'ispell)` somewhere prior to running this code.

Comment: Have found that the function is  `ispell-lookup-words`.  But then I get `(void-function ispell-lookup-words)`.  Is there some `ispell` environment that I have to set up ?

Comment: Ah yes, let me edit my answer. You will need to `(require 'ispell)` first. The library won't work if it's not loaded.

Comment: You don't need `member`, calling `(ispell-lookup-words word)` should be enough right ?

Comment: Without trying to be rude, I think you can probably try that yourself and figure it out in under 60 seconds.

Comment: It tests that an element is in a list.  Why do you use it ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it more clear. Instead of waiting for me to reply, you could run this code yourself and learn.

Comment: Right, because `ispell-lookup-words` returns a list of substring matches